# How to use a loop to save images in different folders in python-opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have more than 20 images that I want to classify based on pixel correlation. I am able to perform all the procedures but the problem is just saving the image into the corresponding class.
Suppose that the pixel correlation values are`[0.48, 0.20, 0.57, 0.53, 0.06, 0.52, 0.55, 0.57, 0.51, 0.49, ..., 0.25]`

And I want to use each index of the above values based on some thresholds to classify the images into **Normal**, **Abnormal** and **Ambiguous** classes. With this snippet below, I achieved the following results however, The saved images are in an unsupported format

```
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, filename))
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
r = []
for correlation in range(len(correlation_matrices)):
    symmetry = correlation_matrices[correlation][0,1]
    r.append(symmetry)
#print(r)

threshold1 = 0.45
threshold2 = 0.35

for index in range(len(r)):

    
    if (rounded_value[index] >= threshold1):
        print('Normal Image')
        cv2.imwrite('./uniform_luminance/Normal' + str(index) + '.jpg', img[index])
    
    elif ((rounded_value[index] < threshold1) and rounded_value[index] >= threshold2):
        print('Ambiguous Image')
        cv2.imwrite('./ambiguous_luminance/Ambiguous' + str(index) + '.jpg', img[index])
    
    elif (rounded_value[index] < threshold2):
        print('Abnormal Image')
        cv2.imwrite('./non_uniform_luminance/Abnormal' + str(index) + '.jpg', img[index])
```

I achieved the following

The saved images are not similar to the input images however classified based on the thresholds

While the input images as follows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to correct the format of the saved images? Or why the saved images are different than your input ones?

In case you are asking the later:

Assuming your snippet is inside a loop that reads each image separately:

I believe your error is on img[index]. You are saving the image as a column, including all of the rows thus creating an image as shown. Keep in mind that an image is a 2d array and with [] you can specify which values you want to manipulate.

***Image[columns, rows]***

Since [openvcv](http://cv2.imwrite(%27./uniform_luminance/Normal%27%20+%20str(index)%20+%20%27.jpg%27,%20img%5Bindex%5D)) documentation says that imwrite takes parameters first the filename and second the image, change your code to:

```
cv2.imwrite('./uniform_luminance/Normal' + str(index) + '.jpg', img)
```

or

```
cv2.imwrite('./uniform_luminance/Normal' + str(index) + '.jpg', img[:,:])
```

`img[:, :]` the : is used to include all values.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, I used index because when I printed the 3rd line in my code as ```print(img[0])``` it returns a NumPy ```array```

Comment: Okay. However, specifying which column to show ( img[0] ) will return all rows of that column. Is this what you want to achieve? 
I suggest trying: `cv2.imshow('2D-Image', img)` or `cv2.imshow('2D-Image', img[:][:])` and compare it to the output of `cv2.imshow('1D-Image', img[0])` so you can visually understand the difference.
Please refer to: https://pythonexamples.org/python-opencv-imshow/

Comment: Thank you so much for a clear clarification